# MySQL slave index file corruption

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I have a MySQL master-slave replication pair, and to take backups, I run a script that stops the slave, dumps the database, and then re-starts the slave. However, after restarting, the slave's MySQL daemon (`mysqld`) fails due to corruption in the `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.index` file - namely, "^@" characters  prepended to the index file name on the last line, making that index file unreadable. Simply removing these characters allows MySQL to start normally, and replication then continues correctly. There is no data corruption in the actual database tables, just in this single index file.

The relevant portions of the backup script (redacted):

```
mysqladmin -uroot -p${PASSWORD} stop-slave >> $LOGFILE

# Lock the database
mysql -uroot -p${PASSWORD} -e 'FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK'

# Backup live accounts
mysqldump -uroot -p${PASSWORD} --routines ${LIVEDB} > ${BACKUPDIR}/${LIVEDB}.sql
mysqldump -uroot -p${PASSWORD} --routines ${OTHERDB} > ${BACKUPDIR}/${OTHERDB}.sql

# Unlock the database 
mysql -uroot -p${PASSWORD} -e 'UNLOCK TABLES' >> $LOGFILE

# Start replication
mysqladmin -uroot -p${PASSWORD} start-slave >> $LOGFILE
mysql -uroot -p${PASSWORD} -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G' >> $LOGFILE
echo `date` Database backup ends >> $LOGFILE
```

What is causing this corruption and how do I prevent it from happening?

Comment: Why stopping the slave in the first place ? `mysqldump` needs running server anyway, unless you're taking OS-level file backups. Don't stop it, take `mysqldump` backups.

Comment: I've edited the subject line because it's just wrong. Replication cannot break the index file by design, furthermore, even from your story it doesn't look so.

Comment: How do you stop the slave? If you do a mysql server after that, I assume that you run `STOP SLAVE` in mysql, but I don't want to guess on what you do. But, as @drookie said: you don't need to stop the slave in order to do that.

Also, please post the complete (you must omit sensitive information) error that you get. It might help.

Comment: Could you show the backup script?